# -march and debug mode

Tags: c++, gcc

I know too much optimization doesn't make much sense for debug code.
But what about using -march=native to make better use of the instruction set?

EDIT:
Let's reformulate this. I know enabling optimizations and debug mode at the same time might have disadvantages like:

> GCC allows you to use -g with -O. The shortcuts taken by optimized
>   code may occasionally produce surprising results: some variables you
>   declared may not exist at all; flow of control may briefly move where
>   you did not expect it; some statements may not be executed because
>   they compute constant results or their values were already at hand;
>   some statements may execute in different places because they were
>   moved out of loops.

So my question is, does -march=native have similar side effects or is it sensible to use it in debug code as well?

Comment: Just try it. What sort of advice are you looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with optimization is aggressive optimization passes that alter control flow can confuse debuggers. `-march=native` may enable additional optimizations (cmov, for example) *if those passes have been enabled with a -O option*, but will not in itself confuse the debugger.